# How to make a font thinner on web

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to design a website and have a problem with font style and size. I looked at many websites to get some ideas for example if you look at this website: http://www.albionwestcoast.com/ and check the font style and size for the name of the team members on the right side you can see they apparently used Georgia for that (in red) but when I try to get the same shape my font appears a bit bolder and fatter and I don't know why.

This is the style I've got:

```
font-size: 2em;
font-family: Georgia,'Times New Roman',serif;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: normal;
```

am I missing anything to get the same effect?

Answer (score 16):

I found that if you add the property `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` the text will lose a bit of its fuzziness and look exactly like it would in e.g. Photoshop (only for webkit though). Not sure if this does what you are asking, but either way it makes the text a bit thinner.

Comment: firefox implements this with a different name: `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale`.
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth

Answer (score 7):

You can use smaller font size and make it taller via CSS transform property:

```
font-size: 1.5em;
transform: scale(1, 1.5);
```

It's pretty safe to use simple 2D transforms in current days (https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

Answer (score 5):

To clarify/confirm, you are looking for CSS property:

```
 font-weight: normal;
```

> See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp

Not all fonts support below 400 weight.

Answer (score 2):

The font-weight property, maybe. You will have more flexibility if you assign it a numeric value, between 100 and 900, always in 100 increments, ie: 100,200,300,400, etc...

- 400 is the same as normal, and 700 is the same as bold

  ```
  font-weight: 300;
  ```

Comment: I tried that but still it seems bolder to me. everything under 600 looks exatly same.

Comment: I f you use the [standard available fonts](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html), 400 should definetly be smaller than 600. Maybe you have a css rule declared after that overides yours. There are 3 main places you can declare css. Try declaring it right on the element with style="font-weight:400;" and you should see a difference.

Comment: I took an screenshot. It seems the colour gives the word a bit of weight somehow. [link](http://img1.UploadScreenshot.com/images/thumb/5/14601514754.png)  when it's in black it seems a bit lighter.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I looked for a way how to make a font thinner if I can't change font-weight.

There is a problem, that on windows and mac fonts look different, they use different algorithms of smoothings.
(see https://github.com/vector-im/element-web/issues/11425)

So, if we force the browser to smooth a font identically then the font gets thicker.

And I have found a solution!

```
font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick to make the fonts look thinner. Use:

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
```

Instead of white, you can put the color of the background on which that text is written.
If you want the fonts to appear thinner, increase the value from 1px to 2px...etc.